# How to compute 1D convolution in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, conv-neural-network, convolution

Suppose I have 2 vectors, data vector:

```
x=[2 1 2 1]
```

and weights vector

```
y=[1 2 3]
```

I want Matlab to convolve these vectors in sense of 1D neural network, i.e. run `y` as window against `x` and compute convolutions:

[image]

[image]

If I run [built-in function `conv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) then I get

```
>> conv(x,y)
ans =
     2     5    10     8     8     3
```

which contains correct values in the middle but has something unknown at margins. Manual for `conv` function looks completely different with what I want.

If I run

```
>> conv(x,y, 'same')
ans =
     5    10     8     8
```

I also get something strange.

Comment: What's the expected output in this case?

Comment: Are you aware that you have to flip your weight vector when doing the calculations?

Comment: @Ibezito desired result is `[10 8]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close to solving it by specifying the 3<sup>rd</sup> input to `conv`, but instead of `'same'` you should've used [`'valid'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html?requestedDomain=true#expand_panel_body_input_argument_d119e158330):

```
x = [2 1 2 1];
y = [1 2 3];
conv(x,y,'valid')

ans =

    10     8
```

Comment: Using `'same'` I was expecting `conv` will use `[2 2 2 1 2 1 1 1]`, but looks it's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the filter:

```
x = [2,1,2,1];
y = [1,2,3];
z = conv(x,flip(y),'valid');
```